# CTRL-M character generated by netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I use netbeans on windows platform to write my code and then I commit it on github.

The developers which work to the same project using unix (emacs or vim editor) are bored to see each time the CTRL-M (^M) character.

Will it be possible to delete `CTRL-M (^M)` character by doing something in netbeans configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably related to [this](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=72515) bugzilla entry.

You can use [this](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=36810) plugin to switch the line endings of the stuff you edit.